# i can't create vite in WSL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

node version 10.19.0 and npm version 6.14.4.

when i write this `create-vite@latest client` i recive this error:

```
npx: installed 1 in 0.79s
/home/victor/.npm/_npx/86414/lib/node_modules/create-vite/index.js:3
import './dist/index.mjs'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of Node.js is too old to use **"Import"** sintax.

In this old version to even run modules, you need to run like this:

```bash
node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
```

So you can use an updated version of Node.js, like v13 or above;

Or you can use old version of Vite.

Current version of Node.js = **20.9.0 LTS**

https://nodejs.org/en/